# HTML5 Basic Drag and Drop not working on Input Button, in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, drag-and-drop

EDIT: The issue for `FF` seems to be that Im trying to make `input type="button"` my `draggable` element. Is there a way to make that work? Or do I need to change everything from `input` to `div`? I really need to use the `value` portion of `input` for my game tiles. Maybe wrapping every instance of `input` with a `div` container that includes the `drag` elements?

I am making a simple game that involves dragging tiles to game spaces. Everything works fine in `Chrome` and `IE`, but not in `FF`. This issue seems to be addressed a lot in forums, but every fix I try does nothing. This issue seems to be occurring in the **Drag** portion of the code. I put a `console.log()` to fire when the drag occurs, but I don't even get that in `FF`.

Thanks for any help. Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpjWLm) and the demo below:

CSS:

```
.tileBtn{
    color: #fff !important; 
    background-color: #e07171;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.gameBtns{
    margin:10px 10px;
    padding:10px; 
} 
.gameTileOpen{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #699fc5; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="gameTiles">
    <input type="button" class="tileBtn gameBtns" draggable="true" value="Game Tile" ondragstart="dragTile(event)">
</div>  
<div id="gameBoard" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <input type="button" class="gameTileOpen gameBtns" draggable="true" value="Open Space" ondragstart="dragTile(event)" ondrop="dropTile(event)">
</div>
```

JS:

```
//allow player to drop game tiles in game area
function allowDrop(mouseEvent) {
    mouseEvent.preventDefault();
};
//drag function
function dragTile(mouseEvent) {
    console.log("this is firing");
    var tileId = mouseEvent.target.id;
    var tileValue = mouseEvent.target.value;
    var x = {tileId:tileId, tileValue:tileValue};
    var j = JSON.stringify(x);
    mouseEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text", j);
    mouseEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";        
};
//drop function
function dropTile(mouseEvent) {     
    mouseEvent.preventDefault();
    //get data from space that player is leaving
    var data = JSON.parse(mouseEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text")); 
    var playedId = parseInt(data["tileId"]);
    var playedValue = data["tileValue"];
    mouseEvent.target.setAttribute('value', playedValue);
    mouseEvent.target.setAttribute('class', "tileBtn gameBtns");
    mouseEvent.target.draggable = "true";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that may have this issue; the issue revolved around the fact that I was trying to give the `draggable` attribute to an `input` element. `FF` did not like that, while `Chrome` and `IE` seemed to be indifferent about it (it worked). So I did have to go back and alter all my code to get rid of the `input` elements, and change them all to regular `divs`. This fixed the `draggable` problem.